# How to get SPuser object from Assigned To field of task

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-workflow

Hi I have a sharepoint 2007 workflow and i need to get the SPuser object in order to send mails to the user but all i can get is a string from the task's assigned to field.
How do i do this?

This is my code

```
foreach (SPWorkflow workflow in splistitem.Workflows)
{
     foreach (SPWorkflowTask task in workflow.Tasks)
     {
         string user = task["Assigned To"].ToString();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string assignedToValue = task["Assigned To"].ToString();
SPFieldUserValue userField = (SPFieldUserValue)workflow.Tasks.Fields["Assigned To"].GetFieldValue(assignedToValue);
SPUser user= userField.User;
```

To make it more robust, you can use `SPBuiltInFieldId.AssignedTo` instead of the hard-coded `"Assigned To"` value.